# Permutation and sorting of Strings (parentheses problem similarity)

Tags: java, performance, strings

This algorithm runs in \$O(n!)\$ time and I wish I could make this a bit faster for larger elements.

Is there a better approach to solving the parentheses problem in shorter time?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    private static ArrayList<String> pathPermutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static ArrayList<String> acceptedPathPermutations = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static int numToEnter, mRankingDesired;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a node and a desired ranking M: ");
        numToEnter = myScanner.nextInt();
        mRankingDesired = myScanner.nextInt();
        //subtract one from the desired ranking to align rankings up with actual ArrayList indices correctly.
        mRankingDesired--;
        numToEnter--;

        //Calculate all permutations of possible "run" paths.
        calculatePermutations(numToEnter);

        //Check for error since ranking is automatically sorted.
        if (mRankingDesired < acceptedPathPermutations.size() && mRankingDesired >= 0) {
            System.out.println(acceptedPathPermutations.get(mRankingDesired));

        } else {
            System.out.println("ERROR");
        }

    }


    public static void calculatePermutations(int nodeNum) {
        pathPermutations.clear();
        pathPermutations.add(calculateFirstPath(nodeNum));

        createAllPathPermutations(pathPermutations.get(0));
    }

    //
    public static String calculateFirstPath(int nodeNum) {
        //Subtract one from nodeNum to calculate all inner permutations.
        nodeNum--;
        String pathString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeNum * 2; i++) {
            if (i < nodeNum) {
                pathString += "E";
            } else {
                pathString += "S";
            }
        }
        //nodeNum++;
        return pathString;
    }

    public static void createAllPathPermutations(String initialPath) {
        permutation(initialPath);
  /*      for(int i = 0; i<pathPermutations.size()-1;i++){
            System.out.println("PERMUTATION: " + pathPermutations.get(i));
        }
*/
        appendCharacters();
    }

    public static void permutation(String str) {
        permutePath("", str);

    }

    //Calculate unique permutations.
    public static void permutePath(String beginningString, String endingString) {
        if (endingString.length() <= 1) {
            System.out.println(beginningString + endingString);
            if (!pathPermutations.contains(beginningString + endingString)) {
                System.out.println("Adding");
                pathPermutations.add(beginningString + endingString);
            }
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < endingString.length(); i++) {
                try {
                    String newString = endingString.substring(0, i) + endingString.substring(i + 1);
                    permutePath(beginningString + endingString.charAt(i), newString);
                } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    /**
     * Re-append the beginning E and ending S to the list of paths we have calculated.
     */
    public static void appendCharacters() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pathPermutations.size(); i++) {
            String replacement = "E" + pathPermutations.get(i) + "S";
            pathPermutations.set(i, replacement);
            System.out.println(pathPermutations.get(i));
        }
        removeInvalidPaths();
    }

    public static void removeInvalidPaths() {
        for (int i = 0; i < pathPermutations.size(); i++) {
            if (checkPathValidity(pathPermutations.get(i))) {
                acceptedPathPermutations.add(pathPermutations.get(i));
            }
        }
        pathPermutations.clear();

        printOutAcceptedPaths();
    }

    public static boolean checkPathValidity(String pathToCheck) {
        char[] pathToCheckCharArray = pathToCheck.toCharArray();
        int accumulator = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < pathToCheckCharArray.length; i++) {
            if (pathToCheckCharArray[i] == 'E') {
                accumulator++;
            } else {
                accumulator--;
                if (accumulator < 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void printOutAcceptedPaths() {
        int numberOfAcceptablePaths = acceptedPathPermutations.size();
        System.out.println("\n Num of Accepted Paths: " + numberOfAcceptablePaths);
        for (int i = 0; i < acceptedPathPermutations.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Accepted Path: " + acceptedPathPermutations.get(i));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you add a brief explanation of what task this code aims to accomplish?

Comment: Certainly it is targeted to solving this problem:

Comment: http://poj.org/problem?id=3644

Comment: If this is code to solve a [tag:programming-challenge], please link and summarize the challenge being solve in the question. Otherwise, this question is meaningless, [especially if the external site goes away](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/1993).

Comment: Certainly. I will have to update tomorrow with the problem summary as I am out of town at the moment.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Answer (score 2):

## Variables type declaration

```
private static ArrayList<String> pathPermutations = new ArrayList<String>();
private static ArrayList<String> acceptedPathPermutations = new ArrayList<String>();
```

It is usually recommended to declare variables by the interface they implement, unless implementation-specific methods are required. Since these two are used simply as `List`s, they should be declared as such:

```
// Assuming Java 7
private static List<String> pathPermutations = new ArrayList<>();
private static List<String> acceptedPathPermutations = new ArrayList<>();
```

## `try-with-resources`

If you are on Java 7, you can use [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) on the `Scanner` object for efficient handling of the underlying I/O resource.

```
try (Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
    // ...
}
```

## Getting inputs

```
numToEnter = myScanner.nextInt();
mRankingDesired = myScanner.nextInt();
//subtract one from the desired ranking to align rankings up with actual...
mRankingDesired--;
numToEnter--;
```

You should just perform the subtraction together with the assignment as such:

```
// Subtract from input to align rankings with actual list indices.
numToEnter = myScanner.nextInt() - 1;
mRankingDesired = myScanner.nextInt() - 1;
```

## Magic method

```
//Calculate all permutations of possible "run" paths.
calculatePermutations(numToEnter);
```

It is not clear how calling the method above also magically initializes `acceptedPathPermutations` correctly to display the results. Looking at how your method calls are chained, you may want to consider explicitly getting all the permutations in the `main()` method, then filter them to get your `acceptedPathPermutations` values:

```
List<String> pathPermutations = calculatePermutations(numToEnter);
List<String> acceptedPathPermutations = removeInvalidPaths(pathPermutations);
```

That means abolishing the `removeInvalidPaths()` call below:

```
public static void appendCharacters() {
    for (int i = 0; i < pathPermutations.size(); i++) {
        String replacement = "E" + pathPermutations.get(i) + "S";
        pathPermutations.set(i, replacement);
        System.out.println(pathPermutations.get(i));
    }
    // not required
    // removeInvalidPaths();
}
```

## Loop iteration

When you create a `for`-loop where the iteration value `i` is used solely for the `List.get(int)` call, you can use the enhanced [`for-each`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) loop to achieve the same with lesser code. For example:

```
public static List<String> removeInvalidPaths(List<String> pathPermutations) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String path : pathPermutations) {
        // consider renaming 'checkPathValidity' as 'isPathValid'
        if (isPathValid(path)) {
            results.add(path);
        }
    }
    // don't think you need the following, they should be done outside the method
    // pathPermutations.clear();
    // printOutAcceptedPaths();
    return results;
}
```

## Java 8

If you happen to be on Java 8, you may want to consider replacing some of the explicit `for`-loops with `Stream`-based processing. Using the same `removeInvalidPaths` as an example:

```
public static List<String> removeInvalidPaths(List<String> pathPermutations) {
    return pathPermutations.stream().filter(Main::isPathValid)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

This uses the (renamed) `isPathValid` [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) to filter on the `Stream` of `pathPermutations` elements, and then `return`-ing the collected [`toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) results to the caller.

## Catching `Exception`s

Simply using `e.printStackTrace()` is usually not advised, and this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469316/why-is-exception-printstacktrace-considered-bad-practice) is a good read on this subject. Does your code really *not* need to handle `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` in a more graceful manner?